# Control not properly positioning programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls

So im trying to place an `Ellipse (named Dot)` on a random location inside a grid.
But it only spawns on 1/4th (lower right) of the grid instead of the complete grid.
Example: When i put the margin of the Dot to `Dot.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);` the Dot will spawn in the center of the screen.
 When i change it to `Dot.Margin = new Thickness(200, 0, 0, 0);` it will have a very small offset to the right but not even close to 200 pixels.
Outcome after creating alot of circles without removing them:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiZ4F.png 
The red rectangle is the spawn area.

C#

```
//Gives Dot a position
public void placeDot()
{
    //Give Dot random position
    // The farthest left the dot can be
    double minLeft = 0;
    // The farthest right the dot can be without it going off the screen
    double maxLeft = spawnArea.ActualWidth - Dot.Width;
    // The farthest up the dot can be
    double minTop = 0;
    // The farthest down the dot can be without it going off the screen
    double maxTop = spawnArea.ActualHeight - Dot.Height;


    double left = RandomBetween(minLeft, maxLeft);
    double top = RandomBetween(minTop, maxTop);
    Dot.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
}

//createEllipse method, used for creating new Dots
public void createEllipse()
{
    spawnArea.Children.Remove(Dot);

    //Create new Dot
    DotImg.ImageSource =
        new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/hitcircle.png", UriKind.Relative));
    Dot = new Ellipse() { Width = hitcircleSettingPath, Height = hitcircleSettingPath, Fill = DotImg, };

    //Activates placeDot() method to give the Dot a random location
    placeDot();

    //Add Dot to the game area
    spawnArea.Children.Add(Dot);
}
```

XAML This is the complete XAML i think there might be something wrong with the XAML but below is a shorter snippet where it does work how i want it but without the other stuff.

```
<Window x:Name="Grid" x:Class="ReactieSnelheid_Game.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReactieSnelheid_Game"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Dot Program" Height="768" Width="1366" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Cursor="Pen" Icon="Images/icon.ico" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" Background="Black" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="{x:Null}" KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown">
    <Grid x:Name="backgroundImageGrid" Margin="0,0,0,0" MouseDown="LayoutRoot_MouseDown">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush x:Name="backgroundBrush" ImageSource="Images/background.png" Opacity="0.25"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid x:Name="gameWrapper">
            <Grid.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.25"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Label x:Name="reactionTime" Content="1000ms" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="40" FontFamily="PMingLiU-ExtB" Foreground="White"/>
            <Label x:Name="circleSize" Content="150x150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="26.667" FontFamily="PMingLiU-ExtB" Foreground="White" Background="{x:Null}"/>
            <Label x:Name="dotCount" Content="000000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,0,0,-1" Foreground="White" FontSize="80" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" FontFamily="PMingLiU-ExtB" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{x:Null}">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform AngleX="-11.056"/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="-8.305"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label x:Name="scoreCount" Content="9999999999999999" Margin="0,0,10,10" Foreground="White" FontSize="80" FontFamily="PMingLiU-ExtB" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="106" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="startTimerBtn" RenderTransformOrigin="0.39,-0.75" Margin="144,10,0,0" Width="128" Height="64" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseDown="startTimerBtn_MouseDown">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/starttimer.png"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <Grid x:Name="spawnArea" Margin="0,115,0,121" Background="Red"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="pauseScreen">
            <Grid.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF81D650" Opacity="0.25"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid x:Name="pauseScreenBtns" Margin="389,153,389,152" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Rectangle x:Name="Startbtn" Height="332" Width="332" MouseDown="Startbtn_MouseDown" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="129,0,127,76">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Start.png"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <Rectangle x:Name="settingsBtn" MouseDown="settingsBtn_MouseDown" Margin="-5,189,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Height="63">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/settings.png"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <Rectangle x:Name="resetBtn" MouseDown="resetBtn_MouseDown" Margin="0,190,-6,0" Width="128" Height="62" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/reset.png"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <Rectangle x:Name="quitBtn" RenderTransformOrigin="0.39,-0.75" Margin="232,399,0,0" Width="129" Height="64" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseDown="quitBtn_MouseDown">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/quit.png"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Shorter XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TESTPROJECTEN.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TESTPROJECTEN"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1366">
    <Grid x:Name="gameWrapper">
        <Grid x:Name="spawnArea"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ellipse has Alignment = Stretch by default. But you set a fixed Width and Height so it looks like ellipse is centered. Try set location relative to top left corner

```
Dot = new Ellipse() { Width = hitcircleSettingPath, Height = hitcircleSettingPath, Fill = DotImg, };

Dot.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
Dot.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
```

Answer (score 0):

> it will have a very small offset to the right but not even close to
>   200 pixels.

First of all, as far as I remember, WPF doesn't use those numbers as pixels, but as some internal values. I can't remember the name of those units, but bottom line, they are not pixels.

Now for your actual problem:

Wpf grid places all his child controls by default in the center, so when you are putting the ellipse inside the grid and set a margin 200, it sets the margin **from the center**.

With that in mind, you can change your random algorithm to make the bubbles appear all over the grid:

```
//Gives Dot a position
public void placeDot()
{
    //Give Dot random position
    double halfSide = (spawnArea.ActualWidth - Dot.Width) / 2;

    // The farthest left the dot can be
    double minLeft = -(halfSide - (Dot.ActualWidth / 2));
    // The farthest right the dot can be without it going off the screen
    double maxLeft = halfSide - (Dot.ActualWidth / 2);
    // The farthest up the dot can be
    double minTop = -(halfSide - (Dot.ActualHeight / 2));
    // The farthest down the dot can be without it going off the screen
    double maxTop = halfSide - (Dot.ActualHeight / 2);

    double left = RandomBetween(minLeft, maxLeft);
    double top = RandomBetween(minTop, maxTop);
    Dot.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
}
```

I hope I didn't miss anything. I didn't run this code, so it might need adjustments, but this is the main line to follow.

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: The result changed: http://i.imgur.com/fEo05QG.png but wouldn't call it any better! thanks for the try though.